# Python 3.x: urllib.request error

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

My code:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

def login():
     url = 'http://rsbot.lt/news.php'
     values = {'user_name' : 'Name',
          'user_pass' : 'Password' }

     data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
     req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
     response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
     return response.read()

login()
```

My error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Myrez\Desktop\test.py", line 13, in <module>
login()
 File "C:\Users\Myrez\Desktop\test.py", line 10, in login
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
 File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 138, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
 File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 367, in open
req = meth(req)
 File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1066, in do_request_
raise TypeError("POST data should be bytes"
TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be str.
```

I've tried encode but it did not help.

Comment: exact duplicate of [TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be str](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440485/typeerror-post-data-should-be-bytes-or-an-iterable-of-bytes-it-cannot-be-str)

Answer (score 6):

The error tells you what you are doing wrong:

"TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be str."

You should use a bytes type, not a str type for the POST data.
If you look at your data type, by doing `type(data)`, you'll see that it is a str, but it should be a bytes.

If you then look at the [Python documentation on how to use urllib](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html#examples), you will see there the example of how to post a form:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
>>> params = params.encode('utf-8')
>>> f = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.musi-cal.com/cgi-bin/query", params)
```

Which tells you how to make the data (here called params) into bytes instead of str.