# Error, Retrieving a web page with data in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a very basic Python 3 function to retrieve a web page with some data but I am getting an error message:

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

def fetch_web (url, par1,par2="",par3=""):

    values  = {"s":"stor","l":"SVEENG"}
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
    req = urllib.request.Request(url,data)

    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    page = response.read()

url = "http://wwww.ord.se"
fetch_web(url,"stor")
```

When executing this program I am getting following error message:

TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be str.

Any ideas about the misstake?

Comment: Lots of duplicates on SO like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5440485/701884)

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about [Bytes vs Characters](http://diveintopython3.org/strings.html#byte-arrays) in Python 3.

And them use byte strings like: `b'...'` for data you post to a website.

Comment: @Wivani Oh, looks like they removed the web version of [Dive into Python 3](http://www.amazon.com/Dive-Into-Python-Books-Professionals/dp/1430224150)