# Python-3 Request parameter encoding error

Tags: django, python-3.x, captcha

I have been working on a `django` project based upon `Python 3`. I am trying to incorporate `captcha`. I choosed [django-recaptcha](https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha) but unfortunately the package is not available for python3. So tried to tailor it for python3. I did some `2to3` stuff and made some changes as per need. Everything seems to work fine except the `url encoding for Request`.

Following snippet yields `POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.` exception.

```
def encode_if_necessary(s):
    if isinstance(s, str):
        return s.encode('utf-8')
    return s

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
        'privatekey': encode_if_necessary(private_key),
        'remoteip':  encode_if_necessary(remoteip),
        'challenge':  encode_if_necessary(recaptcha_challenge_field),
        'response':  encode_if_necessary(recaptcha_response_field),
        })

if use_ssl:
    verify_url = "https://%s/recaptcha/api/verify" % VERIFY_SERVER
else:
    verify_url = "http://%s/recaptcha/api/verify" % VERIFY_SERVER

request = urllib.request.Request(
    url= verify_url,
    data=params,
    headers={
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "User-agent": "reCAPTCHA Python"
        }
    )

httpresp = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
```

So I tried to encode the url and other stuff in `request`-

```
request = urllib.request.Request(
    url= encode_if_necessary(verify_url),
    data=params,
    headers={
        "Content-type": encode_if_necessary("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
        "User-agent": encode_if_necessary("reCAPTCHA Python")
        }
    )
```

But this yields `urlopen error unknown url type: b'http` exception.

Does anyone know how to fix it? Any help is appreciated :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I will answer this myself :P.

Taking hints from an example at [python's official documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html), I excluded `data` from `Request` and separately passed `request and data` to `urlopen()`. Below is the updated snippet -

```
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
        'privatekey': encode_if_necessary(private_key),
        'remoteip':  encode_if_necessary(remoteip),
        'challenge':  encode_if_necessary(recaptcha_challenge_field),
        'response':  encode_if_necessary(recaptcha_response_field),
        })

if use_ssl:
    verify_url = "https://%s/recaptcha/api/verify" % VERIFY_SERVER
else:
    verify_url = "http://%s/recaptcha/api/verify" % VERIFY_SERVER
# do not add data to Request instead pass it separately to urlopen()
data = params.encode('utf-8')
request = urllib.request.Request(verify_url)
request.add_header("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
request.add_header("User-agent", "reCAPTCHA Python")

httpresp = urllib.request.urlopen(request, data)
```

`Despite of solving the problem I still do not know why the code generated by 2to3.py did not work. According to the documentation it should have worked.`

Answer (score 0):

You guessed correctly, you need to encode the data, but not the way you did it.

As @Sheena wrote in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13202998/912757), you need 2 steps to encode you data:

```
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
binary_data = data.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, binary_data)
```

And do not encore the url.

Comment: I too encoded the data in 2 steps. The code you mentioned works fine. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Ah, dammit, I just saw that you answered yourself ~30 seconds before I did! Well, pat yourself on the back and upvote you! :)

Comment: Can you tell me why you picked utf-8? How does the receiving server know you sent utf-8 rather than, say, latin-1?

Comment: I was senting a request to my own server so I knew what I was waiting for. I think you are supposed to know, by an API or an email to someone in charge.