# how do I encode values in soap envelope for Python 3 urllib? (Re: TypeError POST data should be bytes)

Tags: soap, python-3.4, urllib

I understand that data sent in urllib on Python3 needs to be urlencoded and I have studied other answers here such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760728/python-3-urllib-produces-typeerror-post-data-should-be-bytes-or-an-iterable-of) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795976/python-3-request-parameter-encoding-error) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440485/typeerror-post-data-should-be-bytes-or-an-iterable-of-bytes-it-cannot-be-str). Each of those solutions show a dict of data being urlencoded before being passed to urllib. My data, however, is a giant soap envelope and I don't know which of it to urlencode.

Here's the bit of code where I get stuck:

```
        xml = str(Et.tostring(envelope), 'utf-8')
        if self._logging:
            print('URL: ' + self._url)
            print('Request: ' + xml)

        request_headers = {'Content-type': 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8',
                           'Content-length': str(len(xml))}
        request = urllib.request.Request(self._url, xml, request_headers)
        raw_response = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
```

Full code is [here.](https://github.com/hps/heartland-python/blob/master/securesubmit/services/gateway.py) And here's what's contained in the `xml` variable:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soap:Body><PosRequest xmlns="http://Hps.Exchange.PosGateway"><Ver1.0><Header><SecretAPIKey>skapi_cert_MYl2AQAowiQAbLp5JesGKh7QFkcizOP2jcX9BrEMqQ</SecretAPIKey><DeveloperID>000000</DeveloperID><VersionNbr>0000</VersionNbr></Header><Transaction><CreditSale><Block1><AllowDup>Y</AllowDup><AllowPartialAuth>N</AllowPartialAuth><Amt>1.15</Amt><CardHolderData><CardHolderFirstName>evan</CardHolderFirstName><CardHolderLastName>stone</CardHolderLastName><CardHolderPhone>9405947406</CardHolderPhone><CardHolderAddr>627 Woodland</CardHolderAddr><CardHolderCity>Denton</CardHolderCity><CardHolderState>TX</CardHolderState><CardHolderZip>76209</CardHolderZip></CardHolderData><CardData><TokenData><TokenValue>supt_eaztSD0E0uc3SOcdsiRf9ney</TokenValue><CardPresent>N</CardPresent><ReaderPresent>N</ReaderPresent></TokenData><TokenRequest>N</TokenRequest></CardData></Block1></CreditSale></Transaction></Ver1.0></PosRequest></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Note: I have also manually converted this `xml` variable to a bytes object via `xml = xml.encode('utf-8')` just for the sake of passing a bytes object. Obviously, that did not do the trick. I followed it through it's path in the PyCharm debugger and it just got turned into a string again and I got the same error:

"TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str."