# How to send POST data from Python to PHP scripts with basic HTTP authentication?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to send POST data from a Python program to a PHP file that uses basic HTTP authentication. I run this code:

```
import urllib.parse
from urllib.request import urlopen
path="https://username:password@url_to_my_file.php"
path=path.encode('utf8')
data=urllib.parse.urlencode({"Hello":"There"})
data=data.encode('utf8')
req=urlopen(path,mydata)
req.add_header("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
page=urllib.urlopen(req).read()
```

I got this error:

```
req.data=data
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has not attribute 'data'
```

How can I fix this bug ?

**UPDATE:**

Following the solution below, I changed my code this way:

```
from urllib.request import HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm, HTTPBasicAuthHandler, build_opener, Request
import urllib

url="https://www.my_website.com/file.php"

path="http://my_username:my_password@https://www.my_website.com/file.php"
mydata=urllib.parse.urlencode({"Hello":"Test"})

pwmgr = HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
pwmgr.add_password(None, url, 'my_username', 'my_password')
authhandler = HTTPBasicAuthHandler(pwmgr)
opener = build_opener(authhandler)

req = Request(path, mydata)
req.add_header("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

page = opener.open(req).read()
```

I got these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python3.1.3/lib/python3.1/http/client.py", line 673, in _set_hostport
    port = int(host[i+1:])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a1.py", line 17, in <module>
    page = opener.open(req).read()
  File "/usr/local/python3.1.3/lib/python3.1/urllib/request.py", line 350, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/python3.1.3/lib/python3.1/urllib/request.py", line 368, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/python3.1.3/lib/python3.1/urllib/request.py", line 328, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/python3.1.3/lib/python3.1/urllib/request.py", line 1112, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/local/python3.1.3/lib/python3.1/urllib/request.py", line 1065, in do_open
    h = http_class(host, timeout=req.timeout) # will parse host:port
  File "/usr/local/python3.1.3/lib/python3.1/http/client.py", line 655, in __init__
    self._set_hostport(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/python3.1.3/lib/python3.1/http/client.py", line 675, in _set_hostport
    raise InvalidURL("nonnumeric port: '%s'" % host[i+1:])
http.client.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: ''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You opened the URL *twice*. First with:

```
req=urlopen(path,mydata)
```

Then again with:

```
page=urllib.urlopen(req).read()
```

If you wanted to create a separate `Request` object, do so:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

req = Request(path, mydata)
req.add_header("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
page = urlopen(req).read()
```

Note that you should **not** encode the URL; it should be a `str` value.

`urllib.request` will also not parse authentication information from the URL; you'll need to provide that separately by using a password manager:

```
from urllib.request import HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm, HTTPBasicAuthHandler, build_opener

url = "https://url_to_my_file.php"

pwmgr = HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
pwmgr.add_password(None, url, 'username', 'password')
authhandler = HTTPBasicAuthHandler(pwmgr)
opener = build_opener(authhandler)

req = Request(path, mydata)
req.add_header("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

page = opener.open(req).read()
```

Comment: @Kabyle: That's because I copied your incorrect code; now corrected.

Comment: @Kabyle: your `TypeError` shows that `mydata` wasn't encoded; your question code confuses `data` and `mydata`, make sure you use the right value

Comment: Hi Martijn, Sorry to disturb you again, I updated my question. I tried the whole of last night and this morning to resolve this but i can not.

Comment: @Kabyle: your URL is entirely invalid; remove the username and password from it, as well as the doubled scheme.

Comment: I think you mean the `path` variable, I did what you said. I got this error: `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>` Do you think it is because the URL has HTTPS and not HTTP ?

Comment: @Kabyle: if your Python was installed without SSL support then you cannot use `https` URLs, no.

Comment: I resolved the problem by using your code exactly and adding the small answer for this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440485/typeerror-post-data-should-be-bytes-or-an-iterable-of-bytes-it-cannot-be-str#Answer). Thank you very much for being patient with me.