# QPX Express API from Python

Tags: python, post, python-3.x, google-api, urllib

I am trying to use Google's QPX Express API from python. I keep running into a pair of issues in sending the request. At first what I tried is this:

```
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=MY_KEY_HERE"
values = {"request": {"passengers": {"kind": "qpxexpress#passengerCounts", "adultCount": 1}, "slice": [{"kind": "qpxexpress#sliceInput", "origin": "RDU", "destination": location, "date": dateGo}]}}
data = json.dumps(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
response = f.read()
f.close()
print(response)
```

based upon the code from: [urllib2 and json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290522/urllib2-and-json)

When I run the above code I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.
```

I searched for a solution and adapted my code based upon the following question: [TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440485/typeerror-post-data-should-be-bytes-or-an-iterable-of-bytes-it-cannot-be-str)

I changed my code to this:

```
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=AIzaSyCMp2ZnKI3J91sog7a7m7-Hzcn402FyUZo"
values = {"request": {"passengers": {"kind": "qpxexpress#passengerCounts", "adultCount": 1}, "slice": [{"kind": "qpxexpress#sliceInput", "origin": "RDU", "destination": location, "date": dateGo}]}}
data = json.dumps(values)
data = data.encode("utf-8")
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
response = f.read()
f.close()
print(response)
```

However, when I run this code I get the following error message:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

I also tried changing utf-8 to ascii but I was unsuccessful. How can I get this working properly?

Comment: I think your json object is not correct

Comment: @Vincent Beltman, please elaborate. Is it the use of {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, the use of json.dumps(values) or the definition of the variable values that troubles you?

Comment: Well since you get a status-code 400, somethign is wrong with your request. And since your content-type is correct and json.dumps is also correct, i think something is wrong with your values.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution using the excelent requests library.

```
import json
import requests

api_key = "YOUR API KEY HERE"
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=" + api_key
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

params = {
  "request": {
    "slice": [
      {
        "origin": "TXL",
        "destination": "LIM",
        "date": "2015-01-19"
      }
    ],
    "passengers": {
      "adultCount": 1
    },
    "solutions": 2,
    "refundable": False
  }
}

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(params), headers=headers)
data = response.json()
print data
```

I am not sure why you request is not working. Maybe it is really the request parameters that were wrong. The date definitely needs to be in the future!

Answer (score -1):

False needs to be in lowercase in JSON, so you need to quote it in Python, like this `"refundable" : "false"`. Otherwise, your query looks good (obviously you'll need to update the date). By the way, it isn't good practice to include your API key in a public forum.

Comment: This not correct.  Quoting it will make it a string.  The conversion from the python token `False` to the JSON token `false` is done by the `json.dumps` function.