# What does "raw image data, as a byte string" mean?

Tags: python, mp3, id3, mutagen

I am doing a program to edit tags on mp3 using Python, right now I am using the mutagen module and in order to embed an image as a cover art to an mp3 file using id3v4 standards I have to add the APIC frame [using this](https://mutagen.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/id3_frames.html?highlight=apic#mutagen.id3.APIC).

But I don't understand what I have to put in the parameters `encoding`,`mime` and `data`.

I looked an example from here and came up with this:

```
frame= APIC(3,"image/jpg",3,"Cover",open("albumcover.jpg"))
```

But I don't know what the first 3 means? Why when I put `"utf-8"` it doesn't work? And the `open()` function doesn't work, it returns an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#104>", line 1, in <module>
    frame= APIC(3,"image/jpg",3,"Cover",open("albumcover.jpg"))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mutagen\id3\_frames.py", line 65, in __init__
    setattr(self, checker.name, checker.validate(self, val))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mutagen\id3\_specs.py", line 184, in validate
    raise TypeError("%s has to be bytes" % self.name)
TypeError: data has to be bytes
```

and when I put the `"b"`

```
frame= APIC(3,"image/jpg",3,"Cover",open("albumcover.jpg","b"))
```

it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#106>", line 1, in <module>
    frame= APIC("utf-8","image/jpg",3,"Cover",open("albumcover.jpg","b"))
ValueError: Must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode and at most one plus
```

So what should I put there?

And I tried `open("albumcover.jpg").read()` too and it doesn't work.

Comment: The answer for byte problem could be  [string to byte problem that i encountered with Python 3] -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440485/typeerror-post-data-should-be-bytes-or-an-iterable-of-bytes-it-cannot-be-str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the file in either of - `read` (rb) or `write` (wb) or `append` (ab)modes (b - indicating that its a binary file and that we read bytes from it instead of strings) .

For your case, I think `read` mode would be sufficient, so try  -

```
frame= APIC(3,"image/jpg",3,"Cover",open("albumcover.jpg","rb").read())
```

The `rb` indicates that we need to open the file in read mode and that it is a binary file, calling the `.read()` function on it causes it to read the bytes from the file and return it.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `3` means, that it's the album's front cover, [read the documentation](http://nullege.com/codes/search/mutagen.id3.APIC).

Comment: thats the second 3 i mean the first 3 what does the first 3 does?