# submit raw body containing json to REST api

Tags: python, rest, urllib2

I'm writing a rest service which accepts json documents with http post.
I can submit my data using my "Chrome Rest Console" plugin by putting a JSON document into the raw body field.

I'm trying to achieve the same using urllib2.
Using urllib2 i'm not able to post data unless I urlencode one or more key/value pairs which correspond to the cgi form fields of the web service.
However, I don't want to make use of cgi form fields, as my rest service doesn't have any,
I just want to submit a raw json document ...

How can I do that?

Thanks,

J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not flagging the question as exact duplicate as I'm not sure this is what you meant. However from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3290522/146792):

```
import json
import urllib2
data = json.dumps([1, 2, 3])
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
response = f.read()
f.close()
```

Comment: Not defining the 'Content-Type' appeared to be my problem...
Obvious but it kept me looking into the wrong direction.

Thanks