# Reverse engineering a java rest based services from database

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, maven, reverse-engineering

**Problem**

I have a relational database schema (in Oracle, but could be in Mysql or Postgres) and I need to expose basic CRUD operations on tables with REST services, all withtout a line of code from a developer.
Constraint of my problems are: java 6/7 only (not scala, groovy, etc..), maven based solution, possibly framework agnostic (could be separated from Spring, for example).
A mandatory requirement is all of this stuff must run on Tomcat (6 or 7).

Bonus: junit of similar automated test on CRUD operation using Mocks and a webpage to test services

**Possible solutions**

I have already investigated into [Spring Roo](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/), not finding a decent configuration or tutorial for my problem.

I have tried to reverse-engineering database using [jboss hibernate tools](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html) and fits well. Using this tool I can manage to do a maven module (a persistence jar) with all entities mapped.
But I also need a code organization using DAO pattern (to handle entities) and a service layer (to setup REST services).. and this seems to be tricky.

Edit: I've found this solution, using maven hbm2dao, I'm on right path?

Thanks for your time!

p.s: I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070703/can-we-use-java-code-in-web2py-application-code) solution, seems good, but is made with python :(

Comment: Hibernate reverse engineering would work fine, it'd even give you DAOs, you can use Spring for the CRUD operations, and even build some generic base classes having each controller map on a DAO and provide generic CRUD operations. It works greatly with the stack described. Not sure what you want to know in extent of that.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I prefer if you can point me on some example of this kind of stack, so I can play a little bit with it