# Python: What's the difference between httplib2 and urllib2?

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, urllib2, httplib2

I'm trying to implement an *OAuth2* authentication server and for the client part i wanted to send a json request to the server (from a Django view) and i found several libraries to do that tho' the most common are **httplib2** and **urllib2** i was wondering which is the difference between them and which is the best library for this purpose.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:
After searching, i found an extremely useful library called *Requests* and i use this one since then. (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Comment: You can use an OAuth2 library like this: https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2. Or one of django-oauth2 applications.

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to implement an OAuth server, i.e. to be a provider, or are you trying to create views on a server, i.e. your Django app, that will consume OAuth providers, e.g. Facebook?

Comment: i'm trying to implement an OAuth server (like facebook) and a demo client that connects to the server. Specifically this one i need it for the client.

Comment: Related: [Should I use urllib or urllib2 or requests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) handles opening and reading URLs. It also handles extra stuff like storing cookies.

[httplib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html?highlight=httplib#httplib) handles http requests, its what happens behind the curtain when you open a url.

you can send json request with urllib2 so you should use that.
[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290522/urllib2-and-json).

Comment: thank you. Actually i found an amazing library called Requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Also see: [Should I use urllib or urllib2 or requests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026)