# Passing structs through urllib2

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2, urllib, mailchimp

I'm trying to interact with the mailchimp api and I'm having issues with the subscribe method.  I've tracked down the problem to where I encode the data.  It seems to be that urllib.urlencode isn't encoding my struct correctly.  The struct in question is: `{'email':{'email':'example@email.com'}}` My question is, what is the proper way to send a struct through a request with urllib2?

Comment: I don't know what mailchimp is expecting, but there is no "proper" way to send a structure in an HTML request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to their [documentation](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/), MailChimp expects data to be JSON (with the correct content-type header), not URL-encoded form data.

Using urllib2, here's an example on how to POST JSON data with the correct header, taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4998300/2629998) :

```
import urllib2

data = "{'email':{'email':'example@email.com'}}"
req = urllib2.Request("http://some/API/endpoint", data, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
response = f.read()
f.close()
```

However, I suggest you use [Python-Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) which is easier to use than urllib2, here's the same code using Requests :

```
from requests import post

data = "{'email':{'email':'example@email.com'}}"
response = post("http://some/API/endpoint", data=data, headers={'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}).text
```

Comment: Hey Andre, I like your requests example.  How do you check the response for good vs. error operation?

Comment: @arcee123 if the request itself failed due a network error an exception will be raised; if the request succeeded but the server returned an error you should check the response contents and see what the server said; refer to the API's documentation for possible error responses.