# Update an online JSON file

Tags: python, json

I'm writing a simple program to read and update data from a JSON file located here: https://api.myjson.com/bins/3ygu6

I already know how to read the file correctly with `urllib2.urlopen` and `json.load`, but I have no idea how to update values. Can you please explain me how to do that?

Maybe this could be helpful http://myjson.com/api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could work with parsed JSON as with dictionary, just assign new key or change some value. Also I recommend you to use requests lib, it's more comfortable to use than urllib and json: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

```
json_object = requests.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/3ygu6').json()
json_object['asset5'] = 'ON'
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I installed requests lib and i ran the code you suggested but this error occours: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.8.0-py2.7.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:100: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
<Response [200]>

Comment: Oh, this is new version of requests. You need also install requests[security] to work with https (pip install requests[security]) or install previous version (pip install requests==2.5.3) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134512/insecureplatformwarning-a-true-sslcontext-object-is-not-available-this-prevent

Comment: Ok i tried both solutions but they give me the same message : AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'set_tlsext_host_name' maybe there's something wrong in my setup? Tell me if you need additional informations. And thanks again.

Comment: Seems like you need some additional packages: https://github.com/SiCKRAGETV/sickrage-issues/issues/1566 But it would be simplier for you just use http protocol, i've tried it works fine: http://api.myjson.com/bins/3ygu6

Comment: Maybe you put the wrong link at the end of your last comment? Should i try with this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290522/urllib2-and-json (i have to study that before i try)